# Editing a function in R to calculate a score based on a backwards sequence

Tags: r

I have a custom R function that creates a new column for the score correct on a test. `Recall.CRESP` is a column specifying the correct answers on a test selected through grid coordinates. `Recall.RESP` shows participants response.
These columns look something like this:

```
|RecallType |Recall.CRESP                     |Recall.RESP                      |
|-----------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|           
|Forwards   |grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54   |grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54   |                
|Backwards  |grid11gird42gird22grid51grid32   |grid11gird15gird55grid42grid32   |
```

In row 1 the participant got 5/5 correct as the grid coordinates of Recall.CRESP matches with Recall.RESP ***in the correct order***.

The below function is able to caluclate this.

```
attach(edata)
df <- data_frame(Recall.CRESP, Recall.RESP)

split_grid <- function(x) {
  unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", x)))
}

compare <- function(x, y) {
  sum(split_grid(x) == split_grid(y))
}

df$Res <- mapply(compare, Recall.CRESP, Recall.RESP)
detach(edata)

# A table: 2 x 3
  Recall.CRESP                   Recall.RESP                      Res
  <chr>                          <chr>                          <int>
1 grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54 grid35grid51grid12grid43grid54     5
2 grid11gird42gird22grid51grid32 grid11gird15gird55grid42grid32     2
```

However this function needs edited. The answer on the second row of my table is incorrect. As `RecallType` is set to `backwards` in this row I would like the function to be caluating the correct score when Recall.Resp is the opposite sequence of Recall.Cresp. In this example the correct answer would be 1 as only grid 42 matches (the is the second coordinate of Recall CRESP and the the second coordinate of Recall RESP counting backwards).

I hope that makes sense. Any advice?

Comment: You can reverse the elements in a vector with the `rev()` function.

Comment: In case that's not clear enough, `sum(split_grid(x) == rev(split_grid(y)))`